# Possible to store references to objects in list?

Tags: c#

I would like to be able to assign values to list objects without directly referencing them:

Pseudo example:

```
List<int> intList = new List<int> { 0 };
???? intPointer = ref intlist[0];

*intPointer = 1;  // I know * isn't possible here, but it is what I'd like to do

Console.WriteLine(intList[0]);
```

and it would output `1`.

I'm thinking that this isn't possible, but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Also, I'm not looking for an example that uses `unsafe`, I'm curious if this is possible in managed code.

Comment: What do you mean by "without directly referencing them"?

Comment: I would like to know what is in `list[0]` through another variable

Comment: So you'd like references to individual array elements? See [reference vs value types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) in C#. A reference type in C# (an instance of any `class`) is always passed by reference (*similar* to passing a pointer around in C). Value types are, on the other hand, always **copied** when passed around. So, for value types (like `int`, `float`, `struct` and similar) it's not possible. But if you make them a property of a reference type, then you'll be able to get a reference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C# doesn't have a concept of "ref locals" ([the CLR does though](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/23/ref-returns-and-ref-locals.aspx)). So you'll need to wrap the values in a reference type that you can mutate. For example,

```
public class Ref<T> where T : struct
{
    public T Value {get; set;}
}

List<Ref<int>> intRefList = new List<Ref<int>>();
var myIntRef = new Ref<int> { Value = 1 };
intRefList.Add(myIntRef);

Console.WriteLine(myIntRef.Value);//1

Console.WriteLine(intRefList[0].Value);//1

myIntRef.Value = 2;

Console.WriteLine(intRefList[0].Value);//2
```

Edit: C# 7.0 added [ref locals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns) but they still can't be used in this way because you can't put ref locals into an array or list.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible in C#.

C# does not support references to local variables, which includes references to elements of local containers.

The only way to obtain a true reference in C# (that is, *not* an instance of a reference type, but an actual reference to another variable) is via the `ref` or `out` parameter keywords. Those keywords cannot be used with any sort of indexed value or property, which includes elements in a `List<>`. You also have no direct control over these references: the compiler performs the dereferencing for you, behind the scenes.

Interestingly, the CLR *does* support this kind of reference; if you decompile CIL into C# you will sometimes see types like `int&` that are references to `int`. C# purposely does not allow you to use these types directly in your code.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is not possible when using a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) such as int. You'll need an additional level of indirection; You could wrap your integer for example.

See [Mutable wrapper of value types to pass into iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050413/mutable-wrapper-of-value-types-to-pass-into-iterators) for an example of that.