# Can you make an element and an element-in-a-list act like the same object?

Tags: c#, list, reference

I know from questions like: "Is it [Possible to store references to objects in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371433/possible-to-store-references-to-objects-in-list)" that you can modify a **property** on an object without removing the object from a list. So you can make a wrapper class and put your object inside it, then modify the value.  However, if what you are trying to do is change the object itself...

What I want to know is: Can you make a series of objects, store them in a list like structure, and then access them from either the list or the objects?  Can you make **object** *and* the **object-in-the-list** act like they are the **same object**? Can you do this if you use an array?

```
Using System;
Using System.Collections.Generic;

Namespace Project1
{
    Class Test
    {
        Public static void Main()
        {
            int one = 1;
            int two = 2;
            int num = 3;
            List<int> myList = new List<int>();

            myList.Add(one);
            myList.Add(two);
            myList.Add(num);

            myList[2] = 4; // I want this to also set num to 4
            num = 5; // I want this to also set myList[2] to 5

            Console.WriteLine(myList[2]);   //prints 4
            Console.WriteLine(num);         //prints 5
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the first `Console.WriteLine` to print 4 even though `num = 5` set `myList[2]` to 5? Should that line actually output 5 if you run all that code?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Just trying to understand the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at your code example, I think I understand what you are getting at. Basically, you want to access the element in the array *directly* and not by the indexed property accessor. It's very simple to do that, as long as the item in the array is a **reference type**. However, this won't work with value types, because the standalone variable and the indexed property are pointing to different memory storage spaces when value types are involved.

To illustrate:

```
listOfPersons[2] = new Person { Name = "Homer Simpson", Age = 35 };
Console.WriteLine(listOfPersons[2].Name);  // will show Homer Simpson

Person myself = listOfPersons[2];
myself.Name = "Bart Simpson";
Console.WriteLine(myself.Name);  // will show Bart Simpson
Console.WriteLine(listOfPersons[2].Name); // will show Bart Simpson

Console.WriteLine(listOfPersons[2].ReferenceEquals(myself));  // will show true
```

On the other hand:

```
listOfInts[2] = 2;
Console.WriteLine(listOfInts[2]); // will show 2

int myInt = listOfInts[2];
myInt = 5;
Console.WriteLine(myInt);  // will show 5
Console.WriteLine(listOfInts[2]); // will show 2...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The OP isn't asking about modifying properties of an object. He is asking about modifying a _variable_ storing that object or its reference. In your example, this would be equivalent to modifying the `myself` variable itself (i.e. referencing a completely different `Person` object) and having the `listOfPersons[2]` element change.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I disagree - note his question: `Can you make a series of objects, store them in a list like structure, and then access them from either the list or the objects? Can you make object and the object-in-the-list act like they are the same object? Can you do this if you use an array?` - he's asking if you can make the variable and the list item act as if they are the same object.

Answer (score -1):

First, your code doesn't have any objects except the List object you created.  Integers are not objects.  You could box the integers, but C# will copy on both boxing and unboxing so you couldn't use that for what you are asking.

In general, to get the behavior you're looking for, you need to use a reference type (i.e. an object) that exposes a property of the type you want to use.  Note, however, even for reference types, you can absolutely have two references that refer to the same object, but the references themselves are distinct - so changing one reference to refer to a different object won't change what the other reference is referring to.

You can pass parameters by reference to a method or function call, but you can't store this reference (not even by trying to close over it with a lambda), so you can't keep a reference in a list and use it to update the variable that was added to the list.

You could mock up a very cludgy workaround where you maintained a list of `Func<T>`/`Action<T>` getter/setter pairs and use lambdas to close over the original variable before you add it to the collection, but if you're going to that level, you are long past the point where you should take a step back and figure out why you're taking the path of most resistance.

Simply put, this isn't the kind of thing you really should find yourself needing to do - and if it's something you encounter, it might be a sign you've missed another, better way to architect your code.